# How to set for p:dataGrid the last page as default shown page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces `p:dataGrid` component, and I want to set the last page as default page to be shown (not the first page). How can this be done ?

I am trying to generate dynamically `p:dataGrid`components while clicking *previous* and *next* custom buttons. And when I click previous I want to go to the last page to the data grid, not to the first one.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrieve component in backing bean and manually set first row to be displayed (you have to calculate this actually). According to first row Primefaces calculates page which will be displayed.

First add `preRenderView` event listener to your page:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:event listener="#{myBean.initDatagrid}" type="preRenderView"/>
</f:metadata>
```

and in backing bean do the logic:

```
public void initDatagrid() {
  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  if (!fc.isPostback()) {
    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid) fc.getViewRoot().findComponent("dataGrid_id");
    int firstRow = initFirstRow(); // set firstRow to first row on last page that should be displayed
    dg.setFirst(firstRow);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you partlov. It works but partially. Due to condition (!fc.isPostBack()), only first time when I load the page, the datagrid is set to the last page. Then, successive clicks on previous, seems not to pass this condition, and of course, the last row is not set.

Comment: @Ioan you can adapt this solution to fit your needs, it is not hard. Also as you are using Primefaces with `RequestContext` you can filter AJAX requests. Also if you want you can pass some hidden parameter in which cases you want to last page be set. It makes no sense to always set to last page :)